# get the index of the string elements which are common to more than one lists

Tags: python

I want to get the index of the string elements which are common to more than one lists.
Only the 'dog' and 'zebra' are common to two (A and B) and three lists (A,B,and C) respectively.

```
A = ['apple','banana','dog','fig','zebra']
B = ['zebra','avocado','dog','egg','corn']
C = ['egg','guava','zebra','carrot','beans']
```

The expected answer is:

```
A[2] A[4] B[0] B[2] B[3] C[0] C[2]
```

I want to accomplish it using clean and easy way.

Comment: What about items duplicated in the same list?

Comment: @aj8uppal sorry yes, i have corrected it

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart they are not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this,

```
_all = list(set(A))+list(set(B))+list(set(C))
indexes = [[u.index(x) for x in u if (_all).count(x) > 1] for u in [A, B, C]]
```

See the code in [action](http://codepad.org/JIOuCA2Z)

Answer (score 5):

It's actually more efficient to use the collections.Counter data type. Counter works like a dict but can count the items given to it as input. You would use it like this:

```
A = ['apple','banana','dog','fig','zebra']
B = ['zebra','avocado','dog','egg','corn']
C = ['egg','guava','zebra','carrot','beans']

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()

for values in [A, B, C]:
    # Assumes `values` are unique in each of A, B, C
    # If not, then convert `values` to a set first.
    counts.update(values)

for name, values in [('A', A), ('B', B), ('C', C)]:
    for index, item in enumerate(values):
        if counts[item] > 1:
            print '{0}[{1}]'.format(name, index),

# Output:
# A[2] A[4] B[0] B[2] B[3] C[0] C[2]
```

By using a Counter, the items in the lists are processed in linear time. The lookups later for counts also happen in linear time. So this whole program works quite quickly.

By comparison the accepted answer works in quadratic time and will be quite slow if you ever have thousands of elements in your lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, using `itertools`:

```
import itertools
A = ['apple','banana','dog','fig','zebra']
B = ['zebra','avocado','dog','egg','corn']
C = ['egg','guava','zebra','carrot','beans']
results = []
lists = lists = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}
items = [[item for item in i[0] if item in i[1] or item in i[2]] for i in itert$
items = list(set([item for sub in items for item in sub]))
for i in items:
    for sub in lists:
        lst = lists[sub]
        if i in lst:
            results.append([sub+'['+str(lst.index(i))+']'])

for i in sorted([item for sub in results for item in sub]):
        print i,
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python results.py
A[2] A[4] B[0] B[2] B[3] C[0] C[2]
bash-3.2$
```